# My method won't take an object

Tags: java, dice

I'm making a dice rolling program to simulate rolling a die a given number of times.  First I create a Die object with a given number of sides, and then use that Die in a roll method that simulates the number of time it will be rolled.

Can someone clarify?

```
public class Die {

    private int numSides;

    public Die() {
        numSides = 0;
    }

    public Die(int sides){
        numSides = sides; 
    }

    public void setSides(int sides){
        numSides = sides;
    }

    public int getSides(){
    return numSides;
    }
}

public class DiceRoll {

    public static void main(String []args){


        Die sixSides = new Die(6);
        sixSides.roll(7); //ERROR: "the method is undefined for type Die" 


        //Prints out the roll outcomes for the given die
        public void roll(int numTimes){
            for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++){
                int rand = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*this.getSides());
                System.out.println(rand);
            //ERROR: "cannot use THIS in a static context".

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The Error is:

> the method is undefined for type Die
>   cannot use this in a static context

Comment: roll is defined in DiceRoll not in Die, but you're trying to call it on Die

Comment: function main is defined as static, which means that all code executed inside of it - executed in static context

Comment: Cannot define method in main? Just copy from your second comment to the end of the function and print in the die class

Comment: You're trying to define the method inside of your main method. Move it to outside. Note, you will either need to instantiate a DiceRoll object or make the method static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
public void roll(int numTimes){
    for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++){
        int rand = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*this.getSides());
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
}
```

is currently declared in the `main` method, which is invalid in the first place. You cannot declare a method inside a method. This explains the second error. `main` is static so you can't use `this` in there.

The first error occurs because the `roll` method is not defined in the `Die` class. For this to work:

```
Die sixSides = new Die(6);
sixSides.roll(7);
```

`roll` must be declared in the `Die` class. This is because you are trying to call `roll` *on* a `Die` object.

To fix both errors, just move the `roll` method to the `Die` class!

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm so slow.  That make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @gunsnfloyd If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

you must define a `roll()` method inside `Die` class